# get id of html attribute

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I am developing a Java spring project and I want get the `id` of an HTML attribute.

Here is my code:

```
<canvas th:id="${weather2}" width="30" height="30"  name="naame" ></canvas>
..
..
..
```

And i want get id here:

```
<script>
             var icons = new Skycons({"color": "#fff"}),

             var elements = document.getElementsByName("naame");
          var x =elements.getElementsByName("naame")[0].getAttribute( 'id' );
                  list  = [
                    "clear-night",
                //  x,
                    "wind","rain","cloudy", "snow","fog"
                  ],
                  i;


              for(i = list.length; i--; )
                icons.set(list[i], list[i]);


              icons.play();
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines have duplicated calls:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("naame");
var x =elements.getElementsByName("naame")
```

Remove either of function calls

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `getElementsByName("naame")` from the third line and just leave like `elements[0].getAttribute('id')`. Just like the code below.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName('naame');
var x = elements[0].getAttribute('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach :-

```
 <canvas th:attr="id=''+${weather2}+''" width="30" height="30"  name="naame" ></canvas>
```